# Eclipse workspace setup and packaging an independent jar

Tags: eclipse, maven, gradle

I have 5 regular java projects inside an eclipse workspace that have inter-dependencies and external jar-dependencies both
on libraries that exists as maven repositories and libraries that don't.

Everything is working fine inside eclipse but I have two tasks that I need to perform:

1)
Package everything into a runnable jar that I can upload to another computer and run without having to setup 
the same eclipse environment there. I've been looking at gradle/maven but don't know if I need something as "complex" as that
and it seems quite alot of my setup has to workspace setup has to change to use those tools, but I may be wrong.

2)
I soon want to host the code of two of the java projects on google code so the workspace should be structured in a way
that makes that task smooth.

I'm mentioning both tasks since I don't know if they interact in some manner.

How do I solve this in a good way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your description sounds like a perfect fit for Gradle's multi-project support and it's eclipse and application plug-ins. Here's a quick example of how I would approach it.

Your projects might be in the same eclipse workspace but not necessarily under the same folder, so keep in mind the following directory structure assumes you are free to move them around.

```
|-- component1
|-- component2
`-- myRunnableApp
```

The first step is to create your top-level build.gradle file and settings.gradle.

```
|-- build.gradle
|-- settings.gradle
|-- component1
|-- component2
`-- myRunnableApp
```

Your settings.gradle will instruct gradle to treat the subdirectories as subprojects.

```
include ':component1', ':component2', ':myRunnableApp'
```

Your build.gradle will contain settings that are common to all your subprojects, in this particular case we want to apply the java and eclipse plugins:

```
subprojects {

  apply plugin: 'eclipse'
  apply plugin: 'java'

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
```

This should be enough to get you to generate eclipse projects by issuing `gradle eclipse`. Next you'll want to declare the dependencies between the projects thusly:

*component1/build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
    // declare your 3rd party jar dependencies as needed
    compile 'group:artifact:version'
}
```

Now you can declare dependencies between projects - this will be reflected in your eclipse project files when you generate them.

*component2/build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':component1')
}
```

And finally, you'll want to apply the applications plugin to your runnable project. It will generate your jar file along with wrapper sh / bat files for unix and windows.

*myRunnableApp/build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'my.custom.app.Main'

dependencies {
    // component 1 is a transitive dependency of component 2
    compile project(':component2')
}
```

And that's it! I expect this should be a good starting point for rolling out your own build. Check out the gradle documentation for multi-project builds, the java plugin, the applications plugin and dependency management.

Hope that helps!